# For Ubuntu 14.04.5 server what brand and model of usb wifi dongle is supported

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, wireless, usb

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04.5 server on a desktop PC. I need for it to have wifi access through USB. I've tried a number of devices but each requires that I install some third party driver.

However, to get such a driver onto my ubuntu 14.04.5 box, I need to be able to connect the box to the internet...

Are there USB wifi devices that are supported by a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.5 server, out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

Look for one compatible with raspberry pi, since Raspbian is a similar OS to ubuntu. Example: [https://www.amazon.com/Raspberry-Pi-WIFI-Adapter-Dongle/dp/B009FA2UYK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009FA2UYK)